# jssor not working after resiging from admin panel

Tags: jssor

I am getting this error after resigning from admin panel Any solution.

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.$GoToPosition is not a function
        at jssor.slider.min.js:2
        at Object.k [as $Each] (jssor.slider.min.js:2)
        at g.$JssorCaptionSlider$.w [as $GoToPosition] (jssor.slider.min.js:2)
        at jssor.slider.min.js:2
        at Object.k [as $Each] (jssor.slider.min.js:2)
        at w (jssor.slider.min.js:2)
        at H (jssor.slider.min.js:2)
```

Comment: It's very old version, why not download and use the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for reply .can you provide the link to download

Comment: https://github.com/jssor/slider

Comment: Thanks for your help.